# Celebrations in ISLAM

Tags: quran, sunnah, celebration

What’s the issue of celebrating certain cultural events, that has nothing to do with religion?

That’s to say, would celebrating Birthdays, New Years or maybe Independence day be HARAM? I know (at least I heard) birthdays are a no go zone for Muslims, but why is it? What about the other celebrations, I have mentioned.

As a matter of fact, how do we define celebration in Islam?

In general, a celebration can be thought of as going to the movies or eating out for dinner with family as a way of celebrating and rewarding yourself for good grades in exams. A celebration can also be thought of as crowds of people coming together establishing cultural carnivals…..

Which definition/if any other, does ISLAM favours?

Comment: Celebrating when something good happens is obviously allowed, as that is a part of human nature. However, what I think the scholars who forbid this forbid is celebrations that are annual/regular. As in, they are less related to good things happening and more related to a commemoration. It would be even worse if the celebrations include superstitious beliefs or other haram things.

Comment: That's a very good understanding of the situation. Usually, I consider celebration as in different degrees. Eid celebration is at a degree, that can't be replaced by anything. Now in terms of birthday or new year's celebration, I don't really do whole lotta things, in fact, it just like any other day. Accept maybe make special dua to Allah and going out/ spending time with family maybe over dinner, that all.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues first there a Hadith that said

حَدَّثَنَا مُوسَى بْنُ إِسْمَاعِيلَ ، حَدَّثَنَا حَمَّادٌ ، عَنْ حُمَيْدٍ ، عَنْ أَنَسٍ قَالَ : قَدِمَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ الْمَدِينَةَ وَلَهُمْ يَوْمَانِ يَلْعَبُونَ فِيهِمَا، فَقَالَ : " مَا هَذَانِ الْيَوْمَانِ ؟ ". قَالُوا : كُنَّا نَلْعَبُ فِيهِمَا فِي الْجَاهِلِيَّةِ. فَقَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ : " إِنَّ اللَّهَ قَدْ أَبْدَلَكُمْ بِهِمَا خَيْرًا مِنْهُمَا : يَوْمَ الْأَضْحَى وَيَوْمَ الْفِطْرِ ".

My Translation: the prophet came to the madina and the people there had two days people playing ( celebrating ) in. The prophet asked what are these two days? They said we were playing in these two days in the dark ages ( aljaheliah ) the prophet said Allah gave you a better days eid aladha and eid alfitr.

The other issue we have is

حَدَّثَنَا عُثْمَانُ بْنُ أَبِي شَيْبَةَ ، حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو النَّضْرِ ، حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنُ ثَابِتٍ ، حَدَّثَنَا حَسَّانُ بْنُ عَطِيَّةَ ، عَنْ أَبِي مُنِيبٍ الْجُرَشِيِّ ، عَنِ ابْنِ عُمَرَ قَالَ : قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ : " مَنْ تَشَبَّهَ بِقَوْمٍ فَهُوَ مِنْهُمْ ".

حَدَّثَنَا قُتَيْبَةُ ، قَالَ : حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو عَوَانَةَ ، عَنْ عُمَرَ بْنِ أَبِي سَلَمَةَ ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ ، قَالَ : قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ : " غَيِّرُوا الشَّيْبَ، وَلَا تَشَبَّهُوا بِالْيَهُودِ "

The two Hadith point out that it is bad to do what Jewish and Christians do . Also if you mimic something certain people do then you are one of them.  that what appear from the Hadith but to give  a fatwa you need to collect all ayas hadiths and then come up with what the purpose of the words .

Comment: Please give translations when possible, not everyone can understand Arabic.